# TeamCity guest access without artifacts / build logs?

Tags: teamcity

I'd like to enable guest access to our TeamCity server so that our operations team can see if a deployment build is currently underway, as they do testing and during a deployment the environment becomes unstable.

It looks like the very base View Projects role assigned to guest still allows users to download artifacts, see the build log and unit test results.  Since the artifacts are the software we develop, which is commercial, we can't have anonymous access allowing downloading of our code.

How can I further restrict the guest account to only be able to see if a build is running?  If its not possible, I'll accept that as well, and will probably just make a shared logon for them, but it'd be nicer just to enable guest.

We're using TC 2017.1.3.

Comment: Apparently this possibility is not provided.
As an option I can offer you to setup notification rules on the beginning and the end of the build.
Options: Jabber, email, RSS, Telegram (by plugin), maybe there's something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot do that. Give access for guest user is bad idea.

You have to create other user and give special rights.